# Sneak vs snuck?

Tags: single-word-requests

Modern English has changed the way we say "sneak". Nowadays, the word "snuck" is used in many phrases and books. Which one is the correct verb to use in this phrase?

> He sneaked/snuck around the corner, hoping not to be seen.

Should I be using modern English or the classic?

Comment: Are you in the U.S. or not? If you are, use whichever one you want.

Comment: What did the dictionary or dictionaries you consulted, tell you?

Comment: Related: [Where did "snuck" come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35030/where-did-snuck-come-from)

Comment: I **snook** into the library after it was closed and read the Washington Post.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. *Snuck* arose as a regional variant in the United States around the late 19th century as an example of the sort of weak-to-strong drift described [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104015/15770) and grew to become more widespread there.

In the US *sneaked* is still found, perhaps more so than *snuck* but *snuck* is certainly very common. If you use an American form of English or one closely related to it, use whichever you prefer.

Elsewhere *snuck* is certainly now found, but *sneaked* is more common and some people complain about *snuck*. If you use a form of English that isn't American or closely related to it, use *sneaked* unless you really prefer *snuck*, and if you do really prefer *snuck* perhaps consider avoiding it in formal contexts.

Comment: That's a really fine answer, covering all the nuances well.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same question today. I'm in the middle of writing the following sentence

> *...being aware of the additives that get **sneaked** into processed foods and...*

which is to a colleague in research and when I read the sentence over 'sneaked' just didn't sound correct, but 'snuck' sounds unprofessional. Yet when I researched the word I too came to the conclusion that either is appropriate, I guess depending on the circumstance and the audience to whom you are communicating.

Am considering using another work, perhaps secreted will suffice

Comment: Just in case it may help, I'd suggest considering slipped.